# Series resistor or flat clamping for Analog input protection

Tags: analog, protection

I have an ADC whose analog input i would like to protect. I have found two papers from Texas Instruments which details on how to do so.

[***Series Resistor Protection***](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sbaa323/sbaa323.pdf?&ts=1590082856272#page=2)

This is basically adding a series resistor to the ADC input and the input node,

[image]

Applying the methods above if my Analog pin limit is 3v and would like to protect until 30v

```
R = (30 - 3)/ 0.001
R = 27k Ohms
```

And just by adding a series resistor to the analog pin of the adc it is protected upto 30v. Very simple and very easy to implement.

Thats on paper though, I would like to know if this method is really effective in application. For the experienced please do tell me your experience if this alone can protect you adcs

[***Flat Clamp Diode Protection***](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tiduec1b/tiduec1b.pdf?&ts=1590082864823#page=6)

This involves placing a surge protection diode on the ADC input lines shunt the extra current away from the adc.

[image]

Using something like [TVS0500](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tvs0500.pdf?&ts=1590083513558) as a added layer giving a larger over voltage protection. This how ever is not as easy to implement because its not only that you need 6 (do you even need that many?) of them per differential channel, but a slightly meticulous part selection.

Is it worth the extra way to implement this on actual implementation?

Comment: What are you trying to protect from? ESD? What is the voltage level of your signal that you are sampling? There are TVS parts that are designed to protect differential signals with a single part. Example is the USBLC6-2P6 from ST Micro.

Comment: I use series resistors with clamping diodes to protect 12V zero-crossing comparators from 1200V signals. The only difference between the two methods is whether you are using the internal ESD clamp diodes or external diodes.

Comment: @BrianB not ESD just from either careless inputs or  "Stress Voltages"  where there is unexpected rise of voltage. My vref is 1.5volts but i divide the inputs so that i will be able to read upto 5v.

Comment: @DKNguyen oh wow thats a large voltage, what configurations was your clamping diodes? Is it like the same as the image or just one diode to ground per ADC channel?

Comment: @Jakequin My voltages were AC so it is more similar to your bottom image since there is no GND, but mine is a lot more bare bones than the one in your bottom image. I clamped voltage between the end terminals and between each end terminal and the center-tap, and center-tap was connected to cct GND. Note although my comparators could survive 12V, I was only looking for zero-cross which does not require the the signal approach anywhere near 12V so I clamped it to more like 1V. I used diodes that forward bias to clamp rather than TVS but same idea since I chose a low limit , but same idea.

Comment: I have a new design that looks a lot more like the working image and allows the voltage to swing further away from zero and approach the rails and clamps the lines not only to each other but also to the supply rails. It's not been built yet.

Comment: Look for my recent answer on this

Comment: If you want to conduct precision measurements, the series resistor is a terrible idea. It creates significant offset and noise. In all other cases the series resistor is the best idea (with optional schottky clamps or zeners after the resistor). If you want to do precision measurements, look in this topic which discusses low noise alternatives to current limiting: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/565893/replacement-for-low-resistance-jfet-current-limiter

Comment: You want to protect against careless inputs but *not* ESD? ESD will cause hard to diagnose problems such as degradation of linearity. Careless inputs will usually just blow something permanently and are trivial to diagnose. ESD is insidious since it often only causes cumulative damage that doesn’t “insta-kill” unless you use something nasty like an ESD pulse generator. If you care enough to protect against bad inputs, you need ESD protection as well, and testing using an ESD gun. The only way to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

To protect against careless inputs (as clarified), my recommendation is a combination of series resistance with a shunt TVS diode. Make sure to size the TVS voltage for something greater than your signal (but sufficiently less than IC's max input) and then size the resistor so that it doesn't interfere with the signal being measured but is large enough to handle the current at Vcareless - Vtvs. Also, if you are sampling high-frequency (MHz range and up) signals look for low-capacitance TVS devices.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBACGk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>