# Are there optoisolators available that output a photovoltage of at least 2-3 V?

Tags: led, opto-isolator, voltage-source

For [another circuit idea](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/567019/237061), I need several cheap simple isolated voltage sources to generate at least 2..3 VDC and a couple of µA.

I was thinking of a blue LED in photovoltaic mode. Are such pieces available in a single optocoupler-like package ?

I want to avoid putting 3-4 regular optoisolators in series, as that seems a bit awkward, expensive and large.

Comment: Yes. Vishay VOM1271 could be your candidate

Comment: Although recommendations for specific parts are usually off topic, I think we can make an exception for this very niche component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Vishay VOM1271 could be your candidate.

There are also similar products from Infineon, Panasonic, IXYS,.... Google : "Photovoltaic MOSFET Driver"

Answer (score 2):

Depending on exactly how many uA you need, a 3 V lithium coin cell like a CR2032 may power your FETs for long enough to be worthwhile.

With its capacity of >200 mAh, you could expect 2 years at 10 uA, 10 years (its shelf life) at 2 uA.

But they are bigger than the VOM solution.

Comment: Yeah I was also thinking battery, (the current is only nA for 99.999% of the time) but as this is for a protection circuit in professional equipment, I think the optocouplers are more reliable, longlived, cheaper and smaller.